# Accepting the animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**EDIT****

In my word game there is a grid with 3 letter words.

The aim of the game is to spell the words by clicking on the corresponding letters on the side.

When an area in the grid is highlighted it indicates to the user the word to spell. The user clicks the letters on the side of the grid and they move to the highlighted area.

At the moment I have the styles to show if the individual letters are correct, but when a word is completed I need it to recognize this so I can apply the styles to it.

Can someone show me some code that recognizes the correct and wrong words?

**When it was a drag and drop game I did it like this...**

```
 if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
        if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {

        $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass('wordglow2');

    } else {

        $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow4");
        target.splice(0, guesses[word].length);


    }
});
```

**Here is the code for the click to animate function...**

```
if (target.length) {
    $(".minibutton").prop("disabled", true);
    b.clone().addClass(
    b.data("letter") == target.data("letter") ? "wordglow3" : "wordglow").appendTo("table").css({
        background: "transparent",
        position: "absolute",
        top: currentPos.top,
        left: currentPos.left
    }).animate({
        top: targetPos.top,
        left: targetPos.left
    }, "slow", function() {
        $(this).css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).appendTo(target);
        target.addClass("occupied");
    });
}
```

**I have tried this...**

```
        if (target.length == 3) {
            if (target.join('') == word) {

                $(this).addClass('wordglow2');

     } else {

            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow4");       
                guesses[word].splice(0, guesses[word].length);


            }
    });
```

**and this...**

```
if $(('.wordglow3').length == 3) {

                $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass('wordglow2');

     } else if $(('.wordglow').length == 3) { 

                $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow4");
                guesses[word].splice(0, guesses[word].length);
            }

    });
```

**Thanks!**

If it helps, here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/3qaGK/9/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not using a **draggable/droppable** element with an **accept/revert setting**, since you are using jQuery UI already?

Here is a theoretical way to accomplish an accept/revert drag & drop:

First you need to set your draggable to revert if it is not accepted:

```
$(".drag").draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
```

Then of course you need to define what is valid in your droppable :

```
$(".drop").droppable({ accept: '.drag' });​
```

Either you try using a selector to filter the right answers, by setting a class for each letter `(.addClass("b");)` and later change dynamically this selector with `.droppable("option","accept",".b")`.
Or use the **magic powder** included in jQuery UI. You can insert a function as a value for `"accept"`, it's returned value will define what you accept as a valid element:
    $(".drop").droppable(
    { 
        accept: function()
        {
            // add a conditon here to return true or false
        }
    });​

**Edit**

To do the same with your click event :

```
$('.drag').on('click', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var target     = $('.drop-box.spellword:not(.occupied):first');
    var targetPos  = target.position();
    var currentPos = $(this).offset();
    var b = $(this);

    if(target.length)
    {
        // compare clicked letter with expected letter
        if(b.attr("data-letter") == target.attr("data-letter"))
        {
            b.remove().appendTo('table').css({
            'position' : 'absolute',
            'top' : currentPos.top,
            'left': currentPos.left
            });

            b.animate({
               top  : targetPos.top,
                left : targetPos.left
            }, 'slow', function() {
                b.remove().css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).appendTo(target);
                target.addClass('occupied');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems logical. Have you looked at the fiddle, I have already accepted the drag, I need to accept the animation? How would you implement it into what I have already? @Gil Zumbrunnen

Comment: I edited my answer with what I hope could work to modify your click event. @sMilbz

Comment: Add my code after your var target declaration (3rd line). Then copy/paste everything under this line where I've put the comment "//your animation code". Basically at each click you make sure it's the right letter before moving it to the slots, instead of always as you did. @sMilbz

Comment: My answer is updated with the full event code, I tried on fiddle and it works: Wrong letters are not moved, good ones animate to the left.

Comment: Well after you need to take everything you did in your drop event and activate event, and apply it in your click event. But I think it is out of the scope of your question. I haven't compare all the code, only used firebug, but you graphically have something similar if you use this line after your b.animate() : b.removeClass('wordglow wordglow4').addClass('wordglow3').css('color', 'white');

Comment: Thething is I have tried that but it keeps breaking. i dont know exactly where to put it @Gil Zumbrunnen

Comment: "breaking" doesn't really help me to understand the issue. Could you please try to update you fiddle with all the recent updates and your tries to update the click event? It will be easier than doing everything twice and I'm not sure I understand everything you're trying to do.

Comment: When the letters on the side get clicked they animate into the drop-zone area at the moment. I want the letters to be reconised as right or wrong by the woord styles, "wordglow2" and "wordglow" @Gil Zumbrunnen

Comment: How would I now make it apply the style 'wordglow2' if the 3 letters are correct and 'wordglow4' if they where wrong? Thanks @Gil Zumbrunnan

Comment: Will it ever happen if the purpose of your question was to not move the wrong ones? They should always be right. Anyway, to test if your word is finished you can use : if(!$('.drop-box.spellword:not(.occupied)').length){$('.drop-box.spellword').each(function(){$(this).addClass("wordglow2");});}

Comment: The thing is, as it is designed for pre school children they have to know when they have the wrong letter. Meaning each letter should be accordingly highlighted along with the word when 3 are dropped. @Gil Zumbrunnen

Comment: Ok, so remove the if() in my edited answer, it was your original question but anyway: All letter will be placed no matter if they are right or wrong. Then you can add this if() in your animation callback and apply the class wordglow2 in your "if" part, and wordglow3 in "else".

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zumproductions/3qaGK/18/ Something like this? You had an unclosed { and many errors that could be solved by opening your console. Now I tried to make it validate the letters and the word at the end, if the word is right it shows the picture behind. Is it how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Yes that is how it is supposed to work, but it is also suppose to say well done or try again, but I cannot get that working either @Gil Zumbrunnen

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question, you are looking for a way to check the validity of a word that is created by selecting letters, and then applying styles to the word.

Heres what I would do:

```
var dict = []; // Create an array with all of the possible words
var word = "";

function createWord(){ // Creates the variable word to be checked against array
  var addToWord = $(this).html(); // Sets the variable addTo Word to the letter selected
  word = word + addToWord; // Adds the selected letter to the current word
};

function checkWord(){
  var i = dict[].length; // Sets incrementor "i" to the length of the array
  while (i){  // While "i" is a positive value
    if (word == dict[i]){ // Checks if the word is equal to the word in that spot of the array
      // If it is, apply the correct styles
    }
    else{ // If it isn't, 
      // Do Nothing
    }
   i = i--; // Decrease i by one, and repeat until the whole array has been checked
  }
};

$('foo bar').click(function(){
  createWord();
  checkWord();
}
```

Good Luck!
Hope this helps.

-Brian

Comment: Thanks Brian. Looking at my fiddle where would you encourperate this into my code as I already have variable for possible words @bwheeler96

Comment: if you can show me where to put it in I will award the bounty @bwheeler96

Comment: Your original question was about "determine whether it is the correct letter or not", now you're walking us through the entire software and changing your question according to the answers. Next time try to be consistent: validate what solved your animation issue. Then open a bounty for your word checking question which are two different topics.