# click once for each letter

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my game you have to click the letters to spell the words. When a letter is clicked it animates to an area in the grid where the words are.

When I click a letter and it animates to the cell, I can click more than one. How would I limit it is only one letter per cell.

I was thinking maybe disabling the click function for as long as the animation takes but I don't know how I would implement this.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is the click event...

```
$('.drag').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var target = $('.drop-box.spellword:not(.occupied):first');
var targetPos = target.position();
var currentPos = $(this).offset();
var b = $(this);

if (target.length) {
    $(".minibutton").prop("disabled", true);
    b.clone().addClass(
    b.data("letter") == target.data("letter") ? "wordglow3" : "wordglow").appendTo("table").css({
        background: "transparent",
        position: "absolute",
        top: currentPos.top,
        left: currentPos.left
    }).animate({
        top: targetPos.top,
        left: targetPos.left
    }, "slow", function() {
        $(this).css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).appendTo(target);
        target.addClass("occupied");
    });
```

Comment: Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you give the target a class called "occupied" once the animation is *done*. Couldn't you give it the class "occupied" as soon as a letter is clicked instead?

```
if (target.length) {
        target.addClass("occupied"); // add immediately here
```

Comment: Don't suppose you could have a look at another one of my question. It has a bounty on it. stackoverflow.com/questions/11930120/accepting-the-animation @strille

Answer (score 1):

I think you could move the `addClass()` method from the animate callback, so if you click twice you won't get the same cell, like:

```
 var target = $('.drop-box.spellword:not(.occupied):first').addClass("occupied");
```

This is only viable thought if the class doesn't affect your styles.

Other way would be using a flag, so in the begining of the event you would ask `if(!animating)` and set `animating = true` at the begining of the animation, and `animating = flase` at the callback.

Lastly, to enable and disable the click event, you could make a separated function with your code like

```
var clickEventHandler = function(e) {
    $('.drag').off("click")
    //your current code
    $('.drag').on(clickEventHandler);
}

$('.drag').on('click',  clickEventHandler);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Don't suppose you could have a look at another one of my question. It has a bounty on it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930120/accepting-the-animation @Nicosunshine

Answer (score 0):

if you provided the letters with individual Ids you can remove the click attribute via jQuery with $('#letterId').removeAttr('onclick') while animation is in process - afterwards you can re-activate the Attribute if necessary.

Hope this helps. Greetz, Lupo

Comment: If the click event is setted with jQuery, removing the `onclick` attribute would do nothing.